# Get resource path from another java lib res and itself res

Tags: java, javafx

(Ive done it already(almost) but the code looks shiet)

I'm trying to get the path from another lib(My core) res

So basicly in my lib(My core) I write

```
createWindow(null, "Login", "view/Login.fxml", "view/Core.css");
```

This load the files in res -> view (So this is working)

And in my other jar that uses the lib(My core)

```
createWindow(getClass(), "Login", "Login.fxml", "Core.css");
```

This load the files in src -> us.cweye.example (where my Main file is)

That will trigger this function

```
private boolean isSelf = false;
public void createWindow(Class<?> clazz, String windowID, String FXMLpath, String stylePath) {
    try {
        if(clazz == null) isSelf = true;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load((clazz == null) ? ClassLoader.getSystemResource("res/" + FXMLpath) : clazz.getResource(FXMLpath));
        scene = new Scene(root);
        if(stylePath != null) {
                scene.getStylesheets().add((isSelf == false) ?   clazz.getResource(stylePath).toExternalForm() : ClassLoader.getSystemResource("res/" + stylePath).toExternalForm());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ive had a problem with that the files could not be found when i had compiled the jar. So i just did somthing fast to fix it then..idk how to fix that problem

So with all that information i want my lib(My core) to load the files in the res folder and my other jar i want that to load the files in the res.

Thanks for reading this. If someone want they can fix my languange errors :)

Answer (score 0):

Are your files actually in the jar file?

I am using a multi maven project and need to perform the look up like this

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("folder/view.fxml")
```

Where the structure is:

src/main/resources/folder/view/fxml

Comment: My files are in the jar file

Comment: Are you using a maven structure?  Does this run in the IDE?

Comment: It's running on Eclipse idk what is a maven structure

Comment: Maven is a way to structure your application in a well known format.  It handles dependencies, etc.  You should try what I have above - see if it helps.

Comment: That code is same as getClass().getClassloader().getResource("folder/view.fxml");